# How to host a dynamic AngularJS web app in AWS and access it in browser

Tags: angularjs, web, amazon-ec2

How to host my dynamic angular web app in AWS EC2 instance and access it through browser. Adding custom inbound rules didn't worked for me. May be I have done it wrong. Can someone explain the process to be followed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have configured a webserver(Nginx/Apache etc..) correctly on your EC2 on a certain port(eg: Port 80), check your EC2 security group configurations.

[image]

In the above picture, You might set SSH to access only from your IP rather than from Anywhere.